# Need mysql's WEEK() function alternative in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I was trying to find an alternative to the `WEEK()` function in mysql in my redshift database. Tried everything but couldn't match exactly with what mysql's `WEEK()` function returns.

Here's what I tried. Tried Redshift's `DATE_PART('week', date)` function. Tried `TO_CHAR(date, ww)` method. I found somewhere that weeks start on Mondays on redshift. And tried tweaking it a bit and also tried this:
`TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', date INTERVAL '1 day') - INTERVAL '1 day', 'ww')::INTEGER`

BUT, in mysql, `WEEK('2022-01-01')` returns 0 while every possible function I tried above in redshift returns 52 or 53.

Is there something that is exactly identical to the mysql's WEEK() function in redshift?

Comment: It looks that you can (and maybe should) add the second parameter *mode* to the call to `week` in MySQL. Then, you can achieve ISO8601 compliant week numbers and Redshift `date_part` will return the same week numbers. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: @MP24 Thanks for this. But I need something to change the mode in redshift instead of in mysql. Is there a way to change that in DATE_PART function?